# Group Checkboxes in webform in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, checkboxlist, drupal-webform

I have a list of options which needs to be checkboxes and they needs to be grouped together in webform but it doesnt allow, I dont want it to be listbox.Can you please suggest how to do it.[image]

Comment: If there's any chance you can use Drupal 7 I'd recommend looking into the tableselect feature of the Forms API... It should be able to do what you want with a minimum of work: http://heine.familiedeelstra.com/new-tableselect-form-element-in-core

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a field of type 'select options', and as long as the 'listbox' checkbox isn't selected in the field options, the options will be grouped together with checkboxes all underneath each other. You just need to add all of the options in the 'options' box as the page describes (key|value).

Comment: I want options to be grouped into different categories,which I am not able to do as per the attached screenshot.

Comment: Can you have 2 separate fields? 1 with the Island Name 1 and 1 with Island Name 2? Or are they only supposed to select 1 value from 1 or the other?

Comment: we can have two seperate fields but in the end the checkboxes should return single result set for iteration using the loop.